# wait_window returning a "_tkinter.TclError" after unrelated changes to other parts of the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a python tkinter widget which, before it loads, has a window pop-up asking whether you want a small or full version. I used to have the code set to wait until that window was closed/destroyed before loading as it meant I would not get any errors for no files being present. this was working fine using the 'wait_window' method but after changes to code which should not effect this in the slightest, it has began to return the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".56003760"
```

here is the code for the widget, its helt inside the "initUI" function in a class:

```
def Options(self):
     self.Options_Window = Toplevel()
     self.Options_Window.resizable(0,0)
     self.Version = "Full"
     self.Options_Window.wm_title("Welcome!")

     textbox_lbl = Label(self.Options_Window, text="Please choose a version \n Lite is for speeded loading, full may take about 22 days, 8 hours, 13 minutes and 44 seconds to load")
     textbox_lbl.pack(side=TOP, fill=Y)

     lite_btn = Button(self.Options_Window, text="Lite", command=lambda:Lite_Version())
     lite_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
     lite_btn.pack(side="left", expand=True, anchor=CENTER)

     full_btn = Button(self.Options_Window, text="Full", command=lambda:Full_Version())
     full_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
     full_btn.pack(side="right", expand=True, anchor=CENTER)

     def Full_Version():
         self.Version = "Full"
         self.Options_Window.destroy()
     def Lite_Version():
         self.Version = "Lite"
         self.Options_Window.destroy()

     root.wait_window(self.Options_Window)

 Options(self)
```

and here is the code for the main app window:

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("barcode manager")
root.geometry("720x350")
n = ttk.Notebook(root)
```

if you need any more of the code then feel free to ask. I need to try and have this done over the weekend but its not important in the long run and is just really to make this look nicer.

I have been researching the problem but everything I have been able to find has not applied to my case.

Comment: Something got screwed up with the indentation of the code you pasted - for example, Lite_Version() appears to be nested inside Full_Version(), which couldn't possibly work.  It's therefore unclear which function actually contains the call to wait_window().

Comment: Was there a traceback?  If so, add it before the error message.

Comment: i have misplaced my USB with the files on it... i cannot find out what went wrong at this point but i do remember it was fixed by editing something far later in the code (used about 500 lines down, within a module.